# How to correct the polyglossia example with arabic so the formatting is not lost?

Tags: formatting, polyglossia, arabic

I have created a minimal example to reproduce the behavior I'm experiencing.

I have defined a template (`mytemplate.cls`) with a specific formatting for title:

```
\ProvidesClass{mytemplate}
\LoadClass{article}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\bfseries \LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 2.5em}
```

I'm using this template in the `.tex` example below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{mytemplate}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{english}

\setotherlanguage{french}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} 
%\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test documento for using Arabic}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\affil[1]{Author one affiliation}
\affil[2]{Author two affiliation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

%\begin{Arabic} 
%طللك تحديد آراء العرب حيال الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.
%\end{Arabic}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

With the Arabic lines commented I get the following result:
[image]

Taking the comments from the Arabic lines, the title formatting is lost.

[image]

If I make the title formatting definition on the `.tex` file, after the Arabic settings in the header, it works properly. But I want to place the formatting information in the template. How to fix that?

Comment: the bidi package loaded by polyglossia/arabic patches and redefines many commands, include `\@maketitle`. If you want your definition to win, you will have to do it later, e.g. by using `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tip provided by @ulrike-fischer, it suffices to surround the new definition of `maketitle` by the `\AtBeginDocument{...}` in the template class file.

```
\ProvidesClass{mytemplate}
\LoadClass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\bfseries \LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 2.5em}
}
```